# Is there any restart policy in Docker swarm that doesn't restart container if the host shutdown?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want the container to recreate in any case except if the node it was running on was turned offץ

Is there any restart policy in Docker swarm that restart the container any case **except** host shutdown?

Comment: I'm not sure about `Docker Swarm`, but there is option to restart a container
`docker run -d --restart always redis` and if app fails because of error then you can use
`docker run -d --restart on-failure redis`

Comment: I'm just not sure if container exiting due to host shutdown is registered as 'failure' - If it does, than Docker Swarm will recreate the container anyway

Comment: if its the case of `host shutdown`, then do `--restart=always`

Answer (score 0):

If your container does SIGNAL handling well, `on-failure` would be your option.

Be warned:
If your container has an exit code NOT 0 when you try to stop the container with `docker stop` than docker will think its always a failure since only an exit(0) tells docker that there was NO failure.

The magic word here is SIGNAL handling inside containers.

Had the same Problem. Fixed it with correct signal handling.

https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/best-practices-for-propagating-signals-on-docker